# What does it mean by functions of single variable provided the function is of two variable?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, continuity, partial-derivative

I encountered a question yesterday.

> If $f(x,y)=
>  \begin{cases}
> \frac{xy}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}} &,& (x,y) \neq (0,0) \\
> 0 &, & (x,y)=(0,0)
> \end{cases}$
>
> Examine the continuity of both the  functions of single variable at origin?

What does it mean by functions of single variable? This is a function of two variable. Is it asking for the partial derivatives?

May be the answer is obvious. But haven't seen anything like this before.

Answer (score 4):

My understanding is that it's asking you to examine the continuity of the functions that you obtain by setting one of the variables to zero (because we have to look at it at the origin), so that it then depends only on one (the other one) variable. More specifically:

- If we set $x=0$, then we get a function of the single variable $y$ as $g(y)=f(0,y)=\cdots$ (substitute $x=0$ to get the formula for $g(y)$);
- If we set $y=0$, then we get a function of the single variable $x$ as $h(x)=f(x,0)=\cdots$ (substitute $y=0$ to get the formula for $h(x)$).

Once you set up these functions $g(y)$ and $h(x)$, the answer to the question will be obvious. And it has nothing to do with partial derivatives.

Comment: I was thinking that also.. but I was thinking about putting a constant..thanks anyway...

Comment: @Kangkan: Yes, you do put constants there. But those constants have to be zeros in this question. For example, you can substitute any constant for $x$, $x=c$, and set up a function $g_c(y)=f(c,y)$. This function $g_c$ represents the values of the original function $f$ on the line $x=c$. If $c\ne0$, this line wouldn't pass thru the origin, so it wouldn't be applicable to the question of "examine continuity at the **origin**".